# Ansible で、ファイル名が入った変数の拡張子を省いて展開したい

Tags: ansible

Ansible で、変数にファイル名がバインドされているとします。その拡張子を省いて展開したいです。

以下の通り、 `regex_replace` を用いればできるではないか、と思っているのですが、うまくいっていないです。

どうやったら、やりたいことが実現できるでしょうか。

#### 追記:

以下のプログラムは、本当にやりたいことである、「変数から拡張子を省いて展開」をどうにかしてできないかと試行するために作った playbook です。シェルの機能で回避したいわけではないです。。

---

#### test.yml

```
---
- name: test ansible
  hosts: localhost
  user: ubuntu
  vars:
    file_name: "hoge.txt"
  tasks:
    - name: Hello server
      shell: echo "{{ file_name | regex_replace('^(.*)\\.[^\\.]*$','\\1') }}" > test.txt
```

#### 実行コマンド

```
ansible-playbook test.yml
```

#### 期待する動作

- test.txt の中身が `hoge` になる。

#### 実際の動作

- test.txt の中身が `hoge.txt` になる

Comment: shellコマンドを前提にしたくないのであれば、サンプルコードでは[Ansibleの`debug`モジュール](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_utilities_modules.html)などで出力するといいかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@unarist さんのコメントに従い、 debug モジュールを試してみることにしました。すると、期待通りの動作をしていることがわかりました。

何が、問題だったのだろうと今考えている状態です。

#### 改良した playbook

```
---
- name: test ansible
  hosts: localhost
  user: ubuntu
  vars:
    file_name: "hoge.txt"
  tasks:
    - name: Hello server
      debug:
        msg: "Expand file_name Result: {{ file_name | regex_replace('^(.*)\\.[^\\.]*$','\\1') }}"
```

#### 実行結果

```
PLAY [test ansible] ************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Hello server] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Expand file_name Result: hoge"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

置換の部分を以下のようにしてはいかがでしょうか。

```
echo ${file_name%.*} > test.txt
```

手元で試す用に一応シェルスクリプトで書くと

```
#!/bin/sh

file_name="hoge.txt"
echo ${file_name%.*} > test.txt
```

Comment: シェルで回避したいわけではないのです。。追記しました。

Comment: 具体的にはどのように実現されたいのでしょうか。具体的には、@unaristさんの提案のようにAnsibleの機能を使いたいなど。

Answer (score 0):

1つ以上の拡張子をリストに分割する `splitext` というフィルタがあるので、それを通してから最初の要素を取り出せば、拡張子全てを除いたファイル名が得られるかと。

```
---
- name: test ansible
  hosts: localhost
  user: ubuntu
  vars:
    file_name: "hoge.txt"
  tasks:
    - name: Hello server
      debug:
        msg: "Expand file_name Result: {{ file_name | splitext | first }}"
```

Playbookを作らず試すならこんな感じですね。

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{'hoge.txt' | splitext | first }}"
```

他にもファイルパスに関する様々なフィルタが用意されています。

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters